# Obtener el máximo común denominador

Tags: c, matemáticas

Intento obtener el máximo común denominador entre 2 enteros, pero siempre arroja 1 como resultado.

Les dejo el código escrito que no logra funcionar.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<string.h>

int main (void) {

    int n1,n2;
        printf("ingrese un numero entero\n");
        n1 = GetInt(); 
        printf("ingrese un segundo numero entero para deleitar su mente\n");
        n2 = GetInt();

    int mcd;
        if(n1 >= n2){ mcd = n2; }
        else{ mcd = n1; }

        for(mcd = n1 || n2; ((n1%mcd==0)&&(n2%mcd==0)); mcd--) {
            printf("el maximo comun denominador es: %d\n", mcd);
        }
}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué estás usando `mcd = n1 || n2` al iniciar el bucle? Y estás programando en C o en C++? No son lo mismo

Answer (score 0):

Tu error te lo indica @Mariano en los comentarios. Si haces

```
mcd = n1 || n2;
```

C considera el `0` como **falso**, cualquier otra cosa como **verdadero**. Cuando se trata de asignar, como en esa expresión, C asigna `1` como **verdadero**, y `0` para **false**

Así pues, la expresión anterior asignará a `mcd` el valor `1` salvo cuando **ambos** números sean `0`.

La solución a tu problema es cambiar ese `for` por algo tal que así:

```
for( mcd = n1 > n2 ? n2 : n1; ( n1 % mcd ) || ( n2 % mcd ); --mcd );
```